# Making fullcalendar scroll to the current time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

Simply put, is there a way to have fullcalendar scroll to the current time position in the week view?

If it helps, I'm using Ruby on Rails and jQuery

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you mean that you want the calendar to display, automatically centered around the current time of day (of render time)?

Assuming that you are happy that the day columns are always in the same place there is the `firstHour` option in the `agendaWeek` view which might work for you.

For illustration, let's assume that the number of hours on the Y-axix in your given view is 10 then something like:

```
var firstHour = new Date().getUTCHours() - 5;
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  firstHour: firstHour;
});
```

More details on view controls are available [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/)

Comment: Absolutely what I wanted! Don't know how I overlooked this, thanks :)

Answer (score 14):

This is what I used to scroll to the current time in the view :

```
var scrollTime = moment().format("HH:mm:ss");
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    now: today,
    scrollTime: scrollTime
});
```

For UX purpose, **I rounded down to the nearest hour** so user can clearly see where (when) the calendar view is :

```
var scrollTime = moment().format("HH") + ":00:00";
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    now: today,
    scrollTime: scrollTime
});
```

Check the fullCalendar [`scrollTime`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/scrollTime/) parameter.

Answer (score 8):

On v2 this has changed, here is how to do it in this new version:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    scrollTime: '09:00:00'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Version 3:0+

**On Initialization**

For initial scroll position matching to some time on Weekly view:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
scrollTime: '09:00:00'
```

});

**Post Initialization**

For dynamically changing/setting the scroll position (e.g. 1:00 pm on Week view) after initialization:
(no documented method would work but this hack :) )

```
$(".fc-scroller").animate({
    scrollTop: $('[data-time="13:00:00"]').position().top // Scroll to 01:00 pm
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it with this solution...

```
setTimeout(function(){ // Timeout
    $(".fc-today").attr("id","scrollTo"); // Set an ID for the current day..
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scrollTo").offset().top // Scroll to this ID
    }, 2000);
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set Options Dynamically (after a calendar has already been initialized)
then the right way to do this is by using [this](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dynamic-options) link

```
var scrollTime = '10:00:00'; //replace this any time you need
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'scrollTime', scrollTime);
```

Comment: Please note that this doesn't work, scrollTime can't yet be set dynamically; https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/467

Comment: setOptions does not work for View-specific options.

Answer (score 0):

For fullcalendar@^4.3.0 i used [scrollToTime](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/scrollToTime) function with calendar's render range start:

```
calendar.state.dateProfile.renderRange.start
```

so it works for me in this way:

```
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('scheduler');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, { ... })

    var now = new Date();
    var rangeStart = calendar.state.dateProfile.renderRange.start;

    // attention here
    calendar.scrollToTime(now - rangeStart);
```

it works, by the way, no matter what is the `defaultView` value is.

Answer (score -3):

Use the [today function](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/today/):

`$('#calendar').fullCalendar('today');`